# Ngx-Perfect-Scrollbar not working

Tags: angular, webpack, perfect-scrollbar

I have been trying to make the `ngx-perfect-scrollbar` work. I have installed the library using

```
npm install ngx-perfect-scrollbar --save
```

after that I have added the dependency into my `app.module.ts`. But when i run the app it gives error

> Object(...) is not a function

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. All the steps have been followed as per in github repo.

[image: This is the error that I am seeing]

Error is generated from line number 126

[image: ngx-perfect-scrollbar file code]

This is my html file

```
<div class="ps" style="position: relative; max-width: 600px; max-height: 400px;" [perfectScrollbar]="config">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why is the question down voted? Can i know the reason

Comment: Please show the typescript code of the component and not the compiled js in the browser.  My guess is that the `config` parameter that you pass to the `[perfectScrollbar]` directive doesn't exist on the scope of the component. You can use the directive also without passing the config element to it by simply adding it as `perfectScrollbar` without the brackets and the equal sign after it.

Answer (score 1):

Add these line to your component header:

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs/observable/fromEvent';
import { merge } from 'rxjs/observable/merge';

require('rxjs').fromEvent = fromEvent
require('rxjs').merge = merge
```

[source](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-perfect-scrollbar/issues/189)

Comment: also add `declare var require: any;` on top

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when running Angular 5. I had installed `ngx-perfect-scrollbar 6.x`, downgrading with the following commands resolved the issue for me:

```
npm remove ngx-perfect-scrollbar

npm install --save ngx-perfect-scrollbar@^5.0.0
```